# Implement Server.HtmlEncode in gridviews

Tags: asp.net, security, xss

Say I have a ListView on my aspx page. I need to filter out any possible XSS data that might have snuck inside, but I can't Server.Encode on "eval" whatever that is.

I have code like this, and I don't know how to XSS filter gridviews.

```
<asp:ListView ID="MyList" runat="server" DataSourceID="MySource" DataKeyNames="ObjectID" OnItemCommand="MyList_OnItemCommand">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr id="row" runat="server" class='<%# Container.DataItemIndex % 2 == 0 ? "row" : "altrow" %>'>
                <td align="left">
                    <%# Eval("Name") %>
                </td>
```

See the problem? Eval("Name") is not XSS filtered. What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call [HttpUtility.HtmlEncode()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h.aspx), which is a static method:

```
<%# HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Eval("Name")) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<%# Server.HtmlEncone(Eval("Name")) %>
```